# Converting Scipy sparse matrix to tuple

Tags: python, scipy

I have a sparse matrix lets say A.

where

```
type(A) 
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

​
    and A

```
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
with 198 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Following below is obtained

```
(0, 1)  1
(0, 0)  1
(0, 2)  1
(0, 3)  1
(0, 4)  1
(0, 5)  1
(0, 6)  1
....
```

Which represents the non zero elements in the matrix A. (Code below)

```
for a in A:
  print(a)
```

How do I convert this to a data structure like below:

```
[(0,1),
(0,0),
(0,2),
....]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this kind of zip. The main idea is to use the nonzero() method

```
for i in range(len(A.nonzero()[0])):
     print( (A.nonzero()[0][i],A.nonzero()[1][i]) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your question is "How do I get the coordinates of A's nonzero elements as a list" the following oneliner might be what you want:

```
zip(*A.nonzero())
```

The member function `nonzero` returns the coordinates of all nonzeros in a format acceptable for slicing so that `A[A.nonzero()]` gives you a flat array of all nonzero elements. `zip` can be used to transpose the output.